# Exception occurred processing WSGI script - WAMP Server

Tags: python, django, apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

Installed Python and Django on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Wamp Machine. Everything's fine, except a ported version of a django/python website which were on a LAMP machine previously.

500 internal server error when accessing the vhost via web browser

**I get this error log from apache:**

```
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=1788): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Wamp/www/mysite_com/mysite_com.wsgi'.
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Tue Aug 06 12:29:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named urls
```

**This is my .wsgi app:**

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('c:/Wamp/www/')
os.environ ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite_com.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**And my apache vhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/www/mysite_com/"
        WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Wamp/www/mysite_com/mysite_com.wsgi"
</VirtualHost>
```

**folder structure**

```
   \www
       \mysite_com
                  \__init__.py
                  \settings.py
                  \urls.py
                  \manage.py
                  \mysite_com.wsgi
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: You do have a `mysite_com.urls` module?

Comment: i'm not expert in django, where i need to look at to find it? I have in the mysite_com root a urls.py file, along settings.py and the .wsgi file.

Comment: in the `mysite_com` directory, I'd say. Either a `urls` directory with `__init__.py` file or `urls.py` file is needed.

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias - shouldn't it be **mysite_com.wsgi** instead of **mysyte_com.wsgi'**?

Comment: corrected the WSGIScriptAlias, no luck

Comment: You're adding the path to your wamp application wrong. You're using windows, it should look like this: sys.path.append(r'C:\wamp\www')

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the site path to your system path wrong. See in Linux you would use forward slashes '/' while in windows (which you seem to be using) backward slashes '\'. Of course, you need to double them up so it won't be rendered as escape strings:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\wamp\\www')
```

of course, it would be much easier like this:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\wamp\www')
```

And see - your server can find the wsgi application because you told apache where to find it, so it complains about the next module that it can't find (which just happens to be urls.py). I already answered in a comment but I thought an explanation of why you saw the error that specific way would help.

p.s.
If that still doesn't work you might need to append the path to your actual application:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Wamp\www\mysite_com')
```

Comment: followed your advice, new error:

raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite_com.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite_com.settings

Comment: It means the 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' is not being recognized correctly, though I can't find any errors in your code. Maybe try this instead: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite_com.settings")

Comment: Also - have you tried appending the path to the actual application like I suggested?